# Active Adobe Font Not Showing Up In Illustrator - Why?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, typefaces

I have activated the font "Good Headline Pro Bold" in Adobe Fonts:

[image]

But when I'm working in Illustrator, I search for that type in the character panel, and nothing shows up:

[image]

Clicking on "Add Fonts From Typekit" takes me back to Adobe Fonts, where I'm able to confirm that the font in question has been activated:

[image]

I've tried to activate some other Adobe fonts, but they are also not showing up in Illustrator:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Puzzling. Just wondering if you are signed into the CC desktop app on that computer and is it up to date?

Comment: I assume you've quit and relaunched AI, right?